# How to read from a PrintWriter when used with string

Tags: java, io, printwriter

The code says:

```
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt");
write.println("TransformersLegends");
```

What is the best way to read from the file? I can't use `File` or `Buffered Reader` as it takes a `file` object and here I'm trying with a `string`.

Comment: but `Buffered Reader` is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to read from the file?

You can use `BufferedReader` this way :

```
final String PATH = "newFile.txt"; 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PATH));
```

Just [decorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) the new [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) with a new [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileReader.html).
It have a constructor `new FileReader(String path)`.
As said in commentary, a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) will be more efficient, you can instantiate it with a string too `new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FILE_PATH"))`